# Applescript in Automator Application won't drag and drop. Keeps asking for file

Tags: applescript, automator

I am working on an Automator Application (drag and drop) to rename some files. One of things I want to do is strip out the "where from" of the zip file. This script works, except it asks for the file when run vs allowing me to just drag/drop the file on top of the app icon.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make the application drag/droppable?

```
on deleteWhereFrom(fileToClean)
    try
        set posixPath to quoted form of POSIX path of fileToClean
        do shell script "xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms " & posixPath
    end try
end deleteWhereFrom
on open zip
    repeat with i in zip
        deleteWhereFrom(i)
    end repeat
end open
on run
    set zip to choose file with multiple selections allowed
    repeat with i in zip
        deleteWhereFrom(i)
    end repeat
end run
```

Comment: You do not need **Automator**, just an **AppleScript** _script_ saved as an _application_.  Have a look at: [Processing Dropped Files and Folders](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ProcessDroppedFilesandFolders.html)

Comment: Thank you. But, I actually have a string of other commands in that Automator script (renaming, replacing, etc.). Stripping the "where from" is just a part of what I need to do. When it gets to that bit, it asks for files vs just removing the "where from" from the files I already dropped on the app. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: The Automator application is what gets the dropped items, so use the AppleScript action’s input parameter (which is a list of file items) instead of the open handler (or the `choose file` command).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have that now. I can grab the files manually and it works. I was hoping there was a way to just drag them on the app icon and have it work.

Comment: Files can be dragged onto AppleScript or Automator applications.

Comment: I was hoping to combine all my actions into a single AppleScript that was drag and drop. The sample above insists on asking for the files even though I dragged them on top of the app to launch it.

Comment: If the sample is for an Automator application, the run handler of the `Run AppleScript` action is asking for files instead of getting them from the input.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand the solution. Yes, the sample in my original post is pasted in a "Run AppleScript" section inside my Automator Action. I want the automator to run when I drag the files on top of it (which it does). But, after it gets done with the other actions in the Automator (renaming files based rules) it gets to this sample script and asks me to go find the files I just dragged and dropped. I also tried moving this sample script to the top of the actions and it does the same thing. How do I get it to honor what was already passed to it?

Answer (score 1):

In an *AppleScript* application, the open handler is used to get items dropped onto the droplet.  In an *Automator* application however, items dropped onto the application are passed on to the first action in the workflow, which does whatever it does and passes its result to the next action in the workflow, and so on.

For the `Run AppleScript` action, its input is in the `input` parameter to the run handler, which is a list of items passed from the preceding action, and when the run handler finishes doing whatever it does, the result returned is what gets passed on to the following action.

In your original sample, the problem is that the `Run AppleScript` action is not using any of the items that are being passed along in the workflow, but is instead using `choose file` to ask for the items to use (again).  Your script should be:

```
on run {input, parameters}
   repeat with i in input
      deleteWhereFrom(i)
   end repeat
   return input -- return the input items to any following actions
end run

on deleteWhereFrom(fileToClean)
   try
      set posixPath to quoted form of POSIX path of fileToClean
      do shell script "xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms " & posixPath
   end try
end deleteWhereFrom
```

Note that depending on any previous actions you are using, you may need to use a `Set Value of Variable` action at the beginning of the workflow to save the original items (the ones dragged onto the application), and then use a `Get Value of Variable` action (setting its "Ignore this action's input" option as needed) to get those original items in order to pass them on to the `Run AppleScript` action.

Comment: @red_menance Thank you SO SO much for the solution and explaining it to me. Obviously, I am no good at scripting. You've helped make my days easier and also educated me!!!